# Strengthened Cauchy-Schwarz and direct sum

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, direct-sum

Let $H$ be Hilbert space with inner product $(\cdot, \cdot)$ and let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be two finite-dimensional subspaces of $H$ such that $H_1 \cap H_2 = \{0_H\}$, where $0_H$ is the zero of $H$. Let then $H_s = H_1 \oplus H_2$ be the direct sum of $H_1$ and $H_2$. It is possible to prove (see, e.g., [Theorem 1, [1](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1033098)]) that for any $v_1\in H_1$ and $v_2 \in H_2$ there exists $\gamma \in [0, 1)$ such that
$$
(v_1, v_2)\leq\gamma \|v_1\|\, \|v_2\|.
$$
Now let $w \in H_s$ and let $w = w_1 + w_2$ with $w_1 \in H_1$, $w_1 \neq 0_H$ and $w_2 \in H_2$. I have the intuition that there exists $\lambda \in [0, 1)$ (related to $\gamma$) such that for all $v_2 \in H_2$ it holds
$$
(w, v_2)\leq \lambda \|w\| \, \|v_2\|.
$$
Is there an easy way to prove this?

**Edit:**

Applying the strengthened Cauchy-Schwarz inequality between $H_1$ and $H_2$ one gets
\begin{align}
(w,v_2) &= (w_1, v_2) + (w_2, v_2) \\ &\leq \gamma \|w_1\|\,\|v_2\| + \|w_2\|\,\|v_2\| \\ &= (\gamma \|w_1\| +  \|w_2\|) \|v_2\|.
\end{align}
Now everything would be fine if there existed a constant $0 \leq \lambda < 1$ such that
$$
\gamma \|w_1\| +  \|w_2\| \leq \lambda \|w\|. 
$$

**Edit 2:**

I kind of realized that it will not be possible to obtain a $\lambda$ for any choice of $w \in H_s$. Nevertheless, is it possible to obtain an estimate depending on the ratio between the norms $\|w_1\|$ and $\|w_2\|$ of its components in $H_1$ and $H_2$, or on the quantity $\|w_1 - w_2\|$?

Comment: There is such $\lambda$ which works for all $w$. You can make the part $w_1$ arbitrarily small and put $v=w_2$

Comment: @Jochen I don't understand. Since it's a direct sum, for a given $w$ the decomposition $w = w_1 + w_2$ is unique, therefore how do I make the part $w_1$ arbitrarily small?

Comment: Just define $w=w_1+w_2$ wirh small $w_1$ and arbitrary $w_2$.

Comment: Well, but if I'm given an arbitrary $w$ I cannot do that, and I would like the inequality to hold for any $w$ such that its component in $H_1$ is non-zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an easy way to prove this?

Yes. Let $H’_1$ be a subspace of $H$ spanned by $w$. Then $H’_1\cap H_2=\{0_H\}$, so the same theorem implies the existence of the required $\lambda$.

Comment: Correct! Thanks. Nevertheless: is it possible to express $\lambda$ as a function of $\gamma$, $w_1$ and $w_2$?

Comment: @G.Gare I guess the smallest required $\lambda$ is the cosine of the angle between $w$ and $H_2$ (that is, between $w$ and its othogonal prohjection onto $H_2$), but I need to verify this.

Comment: For example, let $P \colon H \to H_2$ be such that $$(Pv - v, v_2) = 0$$ for all $v \in H$ and $v_2 \in H_2$. Then $$(w, v_2) = (w,v_2) + (Pw - w, v_2) = (Pw, v_2).$$ Then clearly $$(w, v_2) = (Pw_1 + w_2, v_2)$$ since $Pw_2 = w_2$, but then I'm a bit lost. Actually, it goes back a bit to my first edit, doesn't it?

Comment: I tried as well doing simply
$$
(w,v_2) \leq \left(\frac{\gamma \|w_1\| +  \|w_2\|}{\|w\|}\right) \|w\|\|v_2\|,
$$
which gives a very implicit definition of $\lambda$, and it's not that easy to see that $\lambda < 1$.